# ContextMenu will not appear on ListView when using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, simplecursoradapter

I'm new to android development and I work on the application for tablet running Android 3.1.
The main activity is divided into more functional parts and one of them shows the list of some items, the long click on the item should open the context menu.
I have a problem, because I can't make it work.

The main activity extends the MapActivity because it contains also the map...
The *ListView* uses the *SimpleCursorAdapter*.

The list view is registered for context menu in the onCreate method of the main activity:

```
  alarmList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.alarmList);
  registerForContextMenu(alarmList);
```

And the main activity overrides *onCreateContextMenu* and also *onContextItemSelected* methods, but this are never called when the item is clicked.

---

I wondered that while using the *ArrayAdapter* and simple string display of the item, the context menu of the list works well and the list provides a nice selection of items when clicked (with some nice fade-out effect). But when I change the adapter to *SimpleCursorAdapter*, the list view does not react on clicking at all. To "simulate" the clicks I have added clickable attribute to ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/alarmList" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"/>
```

And the single list item is formatted using its own layout, which starts like this:
[alarm_list_item.xml:]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@color/alarm_list_bg"
    android:clickable="true" android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="65dp">
...
```

[alarm_list_bg:]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/black_12"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/grey_12" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/blue_12" />
</selector>
```

I have tried to register some listeners directly on the *ListView* instance (*OnItemLongClickListener*, *OnCreateContextMenuListener*, *OnItemClickListener*), but none of them is called.

Could you please have an idea what could be wrong?

Kind regards
Mirec

Comment: Here is a sample project showing the use of a context menu with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants

Comment: Thanks you for your comments.
I have found the problem, it was caused by two things:
1. checkbox in the item view, 2. clickable attribute.

How can I put the checkbox in the item view as it does not "steal" the focus of the whole item? I have temporarily moved the action to the context menu, but I would like to have it directly in the list row...

Comment: I am not completely certain what you mean. Here is a sample project showing the use of a context menu with a `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` `ListView`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/ActionModeMC Note that this also shows the use of an action mode for Honeycomb, so this example is perhaps somewhat more elaborate than what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your examples,they are very helpful.
But once again:If the listview item contains a checkbox (or imagebutton, ratingbar,...),the registered context menu will not appear when clicking on the list item.The same problem is in your example RateListViewDemo-if I register a contextmenu for the list view, menu will not appear, because the ratingBar "steals" the click events..
The only way I can work around this is to use ImageView instead of the checkbox or button and register some listener method on its onClick event. But I don't like this because it does not render the click effect..

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with something like

```
    alarmList.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                            menu.add(0, ENTRY_ADD, 1, "Add");
                            menu.add(0, ENTRY_REMOVE , 2,"Remove");
                    }});
```

If it doesn't work, remove all unnecessary attributes from XML, like `android:clickable` - go with minimal working example, then find out what was causing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this attribute to the checkbox:

```
focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

remember to return false at the end of the function 'onItemLongClick'.If you return ture,system would think that the function 'onItemLongClick' "eat" the long press event.

Answer (score 0):

ListView does not handle long click until you set setClickable(true) method to true

> listviewobject.setClickable(true)

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but it may help someone out.
In my case the Context Menu was not showing because my list adapter had stable ids.

Removing the following block solved the issue:

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```